# issue in creating maven project using intellij

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I'm setting up Maven for a Java project, and I've encountered an issue with the `mvnw.cmd` script. The `mvn` command works fine, but when I try to use `mvnw.cmd`, I get the following error:

```
"}" was unexpected at this time.
```

I've checked the contents of the `mvnw` file, and there don't seem to be any mistakes. I've tried running the command using ./mvnw clean and .\mvnw clean, but the error persists.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to Maven, and I want to make sure I'm using the wrapper correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the full text of the error message you are getting?
Have you modified mvnw.cmd? Can you share it?
Also, try running mvn --version and .\mvnw --version